# How to handle secondary await usage in Promise.all then callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise

I have two calls that resolve promises to retrieve data from indexeddb, if this fails to load data I would like it to retrieve data from the API.

```
export const retrieveServiceRequest = createAsyncThunk(
  'csm/retrieveServiceRequest',
  async (
    retrievalPayload: any
  ) => {

    try {

      if (retrievalPayload.userId && retrievalPayload.serviceRequestTag) {
        const userServiceRequestKey: string = retrievalPayload.userId + '_' + retrievalPayload.serviceRequestTag;
        await Promise.all([
          csmIndexedDbService.getCSMData(CSM_Stores.CSM_SR_EDITED, userServiceRequestKey),
          csmIndexedDbService.getCSMData(CSM_Stores.CSM_SR_UNEDITED, userServiceRequestKey)
        ])
        .then (requestDataArray => {
          if (requestDataArray.length > 0 && requestDataArray[0]){
            return { serviceRequest: requestDataArray[0], serviceRequestOriginal: requestDataArray[1], isDirty: true, addToStore: true }
          } else {
            return await csmRequestDataService.getServiceRequest(retrievalPayload.serviceRequestId);
          }
        })
        .catch (error => 
          console.log(error)
        );
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    }
  }
);
```

The piece that I am unsure about is:

```
return await csmRequestDataService.getServiceRequest(retrievalPayload.serviceRequestId);
```

Awaiting the API gives an error:

> 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the
> top levels of modules

How should I handle await for a second round?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the `then` handler async, but it's better not to mix the two styles. Assign the result of the `await`ed expression to a variable, then use it directly, without the need for a `then` handler.

```js
export const retrieveServiceRequest = createAsyncThunk(
  'csm/retrieveServiceRequest',
  async (
    retrievalPayload: any
  ) => {

    try {

      if (retrievalPayload.userId && retrievalPayload.serviceRequestTag) {
        const userServiceRequestKey: string = retrievalPayload.userId + '_' + retrievalPayload.serviceRequestTag;
        
        // assign to variable .
        const requestDataArray = await Promise.all([
          csmIndexedDbService.getCSMData(CSM_Stores.CSM_SR_EDITED, userServiceRequestKey),
          csmIndexedDbService.getCSMData(CSM_Stores.CSM_SR_UNEDITED, userServiceRequestKey)
        ])

        // move out of .then handler
        if (requestDataArray.length > 0 && requestDataArray[0]){
          return { serviceRequest: requestDataArray[0], serviceRequestOriginal: requestDataArray[1], isDirty: true, addToStore: true }
        } else {
          return await csmRequestDataService.getServiceRequest(retrievalPayload.serviceRequestId);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    }
  }
);
```

Don't swallow errors with `try..catch` and `console.error`, simply let them bubble up -

```js
export const retrieveServiceRequest = createAsyncThunk(
  'csm/retrieveServiceRequest',
  async (
    retrievalPayload: any
  ) => {
     if (retrievalPayload.userId && retrievalPayload.serviceRequestTag) {
      const userServiceRequestKey: string = retrievalPayload.userId + '_' + retrievalPayload.serviceRequestTag;
      
      const requestDataArray = await Promise.all([
        csmIndexedDbService.getCSMData(CSM_Stores.CSM_SR_EDITED, userServiceRequestKey),
        csmIndexedDbService.getCSMData(CSM_Stores.CSM_SR_UNEDITED, userServiceRequestKey)
      ])

      if (requestDataArray.length > 0 && requestDataArray[0]){
        return { serviceRequest: requestDataArray[0], serviceRequestOriginal: requestDataArray[1], isDirty: true, addToStore: true }
      } else {
        return await csmRequestDataService.getServiceRequest(retrievalPayload.serviceRequestId);
      }
    }
  }
);
```

The caller is allowed to handle them however they wish -

```js
retrieveServiceRequest.catch(console.error)
```

Finally avoid `return-await ...` anti-pattern. All `async` functions implicitly return a promise -

```js
export const retrieveServiceRequest = createAsyncThunk(
  'csm/retrieveServiceRequest',
  async (
    retrievalPayload: any
  ) => {
     if (retrievalPayload.userId && retrievalPayload.serviceRequestTag) {
      const userServiceRequestKey: string = retrievalPayload.userId + '_' + retrievalPayload.serviceRequestTag;
      
      const requestDataArray = await Promise.all([
        csmIndexedDbService.getCSMData(CSM_Stores.CSM_SR_EDITED, userServiceRequestKey),
        csmIndexedDbService.getCSMData(CSM_Stores.CSM_SR_UNEDITED, userServiceRequestKey)
      ])

      if (requestDataArray.length > 0 && requestDataArray[0]){
        return { serviceRequest: requestDataArray[0], serviceRequestOriginal: requestDataArray[1], isDirty: true, addToStore: true }
      } else {
        // this does the exact same thing
        return csmRequestDataService.getServiceRequest(retrievalPayload.serviceRequestId);
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Hopefully this helps you see the elegance and simplicity of the `async..await` pattern. When used correctly, it allows the writer to seamlessly and effortlessly transition between sychronous and asynchronous control flow.